# Spark PySpark Increasing value lag/last function with window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this (pyspark)

| customer | date | col_x | day_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/10/2022 | ...(val doesn't matter) | NULL |
| 1 | 5/11/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 1 | 5/12/2022 | ... | 0 |
| 1 | 5/13/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 1 | 5/14/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 1 | 5/15/2022 | ... | 3 |
| 1 | 5/16/2022 | ... | 4 |
| 1 | 5/17/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 1 | 5/18/2022 | ... | 6 |
| 2 | 5/10/2022 | ...(val doesn't matter) | NULL |
| 2 | 5/11/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 2 | 5/12/2022 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | 5/13/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 2 | 5/14/2022 | ... | 2 |
| 2 | 5/15/2022 | ... | 3 |
| 2 | 5/16/2022 | ... | NULL |
| 2 | 5/17/2022 | ... | 5 |
| 2 | 5/18/2022 | ... | NULL |

and this pattern repeats for a number of customer.

What I would like to have is to fill the number between (for example for customer 1 on 5/13 and 5/14 the day number would be 1 and 2) and it should always be increasing by 1 since EVERY date value is populated.

I have tried a lag function and I believe this would work (code below) but I am wondering if there is any other way to do this, perhaps with `row_number()` starting from the first non-null `day_number` value for each grouping.

This is what I have tried

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy("customer").orderBy("date")


#LAG FUNCTION SEEMS TO WORK
df.select(
F.coalesce(F.col("day_number"), F.lit(F.lag(F.col("day_number")).over(window)) + 1)
)
#SOME ROW_NUMBER() FUNCTION , DOES NOT WORK -- 
df.select(
F.coalesce(F.col("day_number"), F.row_number().over(window) + F.lit(F.min("day_number").over(window) - 1)).alias("day_number")
)
```

Would be curious if/what the other solutions are out there, I also was thinking there is a way to use `F.last()`, but there would need to be a way to add the offset (+1,+2,+3) etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution can definitely be done this way:

```
window = Window.partitionBy("customer").orderBy("date")

df.select(F.when(F.datediff(F.col("date"),F.first(F.when(F.col("day_number") == 0, F.col("date")), ignorenulls=True).over(fill_window))>=0,F.datediff(F.col("date"),F.first(F.when(F.col("day_number") == 0, F.col("date")), ignorenulls=True).over(fill_window))).alias("day_number_test")
```

but it doesn't seem like the prettiest solution, I'd be curious to know if any others exist which incorporate into a window function right away.